# Vogels DynamoDB error to migrate to newer api

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I'm using Vogels DynamoDB data mapper for node.js - and have been having really difficult time getting to work in DynamoDB (on AWS). For DynamoDB local there are **NO** issues - it sets up the schema and works perfectly in the node.js app.

However, when deploying to AWS - getting the following error:

```
Details:Error: define no longer accepts schema callback, migrate to new api
```

Thing is that I'm using the latest version of Vogels (https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels)

So why is it saying to migrate to a new api?

Answer (score 0):

`callback` in `define` was removed in Vogels 2.0:
https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels/commit/6d5e70e4fdcfd5f28058298bc63cf749d15837a9

The second parameter in `define` is now schema. If you pass a function as a second parameter, you get this error, since Vogel thinks your're trying to use Vogels 1.x:

```
if(_.isFunction(config)) {
  throw new Error('define no longer accepts schema callback, migrate to new api');
}
```

Source: https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels/commit/6d5e70e4fdcfd5f28058298bc63cf749d15837a9#diff-6d186b954a58d5bb740f73d84fe39073R121

So check the second parameter in your `define` calls. That should be a schema in JSON format, not a function. An example from official docs:

```
var Account = vogels.define('Account', {
  hashKey : 'email',

  // add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps : true,

  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    name    : Joi.string(),
    age     : Joi.number(),
    roles   : vogels.types.stringSet(),
    settings : {
      nickname      : Joi.string(),
      acceptedTerms : Joi.boolean().default(false)
    }
  }
});
```